# How to make a picture taking the maximum space?

Tags: graphics, floats, scale

To expand a picture imported with `\includegraphics` that is wider than heigh to the width of the text block, you just do this:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ ... }
```

When they are heigher than wide, you could do pretty much the same with the text height:

```
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ ... }
```

However, because pictures are often included in floats, there is a caption. This caption has a certain height and `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ ... }` make the figure overflow in the margin.

This leads to the following:

1. Is there a way to tell to `\includegraphics` that the height of the picture must be the difference between `\textheight` and the height of the caption (with the needed space around of course)?
2. How to generalise this kind of behaviour to the case where there are several floats or subfloats in the same “row” or “column” by saying to `\includegraphics` something like “take the maximum allowed space”?

I think it could be more general and maybe someone else could expand or precise this.

---

daleif suggested to use the adjustbox package. It is very interesting and gives access to the maximum dimensions of pictures.

I tried two interesting things:

1. To use `\adjincludegraphics` in place of `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment:

   ```
   \begin{figure}
     \adjincludegraphics[max height=\textheight]{ ... }
   \caption{Some text}
   ```

   I also tried `max totalheight`, but I don’t see a difference (the manual doesn’t say anything about it.) This doesn’t work: the picture is scaled but the caption is still outside the margins.
2. To use the `adjustbox` environment which can emulate floats:

   ```
   \begin{adjustbox}{float=figure,caption={Some text}, max height=\textheight}
     \includegraphics{ ... }
   \end{adjustbox}
   ```

   This does not work unless I remove `float=figure` (and then there is no caption.) The `figure` (alone) option doesn’t work either. With `float=figure`, there is *absolutely* nothing appearing in the document but a blank page.

I think the second solution is better, but I can’t get it working properly.

Comment: Of course you cannot use `max-height=\textheight`, then there is no room left for the caption. Perhaps something like `max height=0.9\textheight,max width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio` is better for your needs

Comment: Also if you use the `export` (AFAIR) option for `adjustbox` those options also apply directly to `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 3):

See the `adjustbox` package, it can add features to `\includegraphics`, including an `max width/max height` option that might be useful in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have issues with adjustbox. I edited my first post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the used keys is important. As you create a float the resizing must be done beforehand, i.e. `max height` first, then define the `caption` and finally tell `adjustbox` that you want a figure (`figure` key or `float=figure`). 
If you use the `caption` key after `figure` it comes to late. `max height` after `figure` will create a `figure` environment inside a `\resizebox` which does not work.

You should use `\textheight-\baselineskip` as maximum height as you still need space for the caption (increase to `2\baselineskip` if you have a two line caption and so on).

Note that there is also `\adjustimage` which reduces the amount of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example text and image only

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{max height=\textheight-\baselineskip,center,caption={Some text},float=figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a3}
\end{adjustbox}
% or just
%\adjustimage{max height=\textheight-\baselineskip,center,caption={Some %text},float=figure}{example-image-a3}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```